# react-native-render-html: "You seem to update the X prop of the Y component in short periods of time..."

Tags: react-native, react-native-render-html

*Notes: I'm the author of `react-native-render-html`. This question is for educational purposes, [in compliance with StackOverflow policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).*

[image]

I am rendering `RenderHtml` component in a `WebDisplay` component like so:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions} from 'react-native';
import RenderHtml from 'react-native-render-html';

const html = '<div>Hello world!</div>';

function WebDisplay({html}) {
  const {width: contentWidth} = useWindowDimensions();
  const tagsStyles = {
    a: {
      textDecorationLine: 'none',
    },
  };
  return (
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={contentWidth}
      source={{html}}
      tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
    />
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [isToastVisible, setIsToastVisible] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(function flipToast() {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsToastVisible((v) => !v);
    }, 30);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  });
  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <WebDisplay html={html} />
      {isToastVisible && <Text>This is a toast!</Text>}
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});
```

Why am I getting this warning, what does it mean and how to fix it?

Comment: I hit this issue with iOS home button/gesture - leaving the warning is the right thing to do. This happens because iOS changes btwn light/dark mode when leaving the app in order to grab screenshots: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28525

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Usually, this warning shows up when:

- The parent (currently `App`) component updates very often and causes `WebDisplay` component to re-render. In the provided snippet, every 30 milliseconds;
- At least one prop passed to `RenderHTML` is referentially unstable between each re-render. In the provided snippet, `tagsStyles` reference changes on every re-render.

Notice that between every update of the `App` component caused by the `useEffect` hook, the `html` prop passed to `WebDisplay` is unchanged. But `WebDisplay` is re-rendered anyway because it is not "pure".

For this very reason, a pretty straightforward solution is to wrap `WebDisplay` in `React.memo`:

```js
const WebDisplay = React.memo(function WebDisplay({html}) {
  const {width: contentWidth} = useWindowDimensions();
  const tagsStyles = {
    a: {
      textDecorationLine: 'none',
    },
  };
  return (
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={contentWidth}
      source={{html}}
      tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
    />
  );
});
```

You can learn more about this technique [in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

> **Note**: "pure" terminology comes from React [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) class. I think `React.pure` would have been less ambiguous than `React.memo` because we now use "memoization" to designate optimization techniques applying to both components and props, which can be confusing. I prefer to preserve "pure" terminology for components, and "memoization" for props.

Another solution is to move `tagsStyles` outside the `WebDisplay` function body. In that case, it will be instantiated only once and become referentially stable. Because `RenderHtml` itself is pure, it won't re-render its own subcomponents and the warning should disappear:

```js
const tagsStyles = {
  a: {
    textDecorationLine: 'none',
  },
};

function WebDisplay({html}) {
  const {width: contentWidth} = useWindowDimensions();
  return (
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={contentWidth}
      source={{html}}
      tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
    />
  );
};
```

> **Note**: It's a great habit to move any props which does not depend on any other state or prop outside of the body of a functional component.

Finally, if your use case involves `tagsStyles` depending on a prop, you could memoize it with `React.useMemo`:

```js
function WebDisplay({html, anchorColor}) {
  const {width: contentWidth} = useWindowDimensions();
  const tagsStyles = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      a: {
        color: anchorColor,
        textDecorationLine: 'none',
      },
    }),
    [anchorColor],
  );
  return (
    <RenderHtml
      contentWidth={contentWidth}
      source={{html}}
      tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
    />
  );
}
```

More information on this hook [in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

If you still don't have a clear mental model of how component updates work in React, I suggest those readings to enhance your skills:

- [reactjs.org, Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)
- [reactjs.org, Optimizing Performance, Avoid Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#avoid-reconciliation)

Comment: Thanks for this, @Jules. It gave me some good clues to hunt down my problem. As a reminder for other readers, remember that both state updates and context updates cause re-renders. In my case, I had dealt with all the state updates, and re-ordered them so that the RenderHtml component would get rendered last, but I still had a context update that was causing a re-render after the state updates.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i solved this error to do that
//make const

const MemoizedRenderHtml = React.memo(RenderHtml);

then call it in return

```
<MemoizedRenderHtml
    contentWidth={width}
    baseStyle={renderHtmlTagsStyles}
     source={{ html: textToDisplay }}
      />
```

try this you can get rid of this error simple

Answer (score 0):

Removing this prop, `enableExperimentalBRCollapsing={true}`, from `<RenderHtml />` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue with iOS home button/gesture - leaving the warning is the right thing to do. This happens because iOS changes btwn light/dark mode when leaving the app in order to grab screenshots: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28525